# it is possible to have a constraint that does not contain any decision variables

Tags: optimization, constraint, ampl

I had formulated an optimization model, and along the way I had to change a variable into a parameter. In doing so, one of my constraints that contained the variable I changed no longer contained a decision variable; however, the model solved alright. I want to know if it is possible to have a constraint that does not contain any decision variables.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: I am using AMPL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Constraints define your feasibility region; bounds your search space. A constraint with no dv (decision or optimization variable) simply becomes a testing condition. If parameter value satisfies the constraint, it evaluates the objective value, if not it throws a infeasible/out of bounds error.

Comment: Thank you very much.